# Tycho Compiler Plugin: "No implementation for org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JdkLibraryInfoProvider was bound"

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, tycho

I'm trying to build an Eclipse RCP application using Tycho 1.4.0 (with manifest-first paradigm) and Maven 3.6.1.

Project layout and pom files are mostly similar to [this example](https://github.com/eclipse/tycho-demo) but Maven/Tycho fails to compile the project giving this error message:

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.331 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-08-09T08:54:24+03:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 38M/92M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.codeaffine.util: Execution default-compile of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0:compile failed: Unable to provision, see the following errors:
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1) No implementation for org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JdkLibraryInfoProvider was bound.
[ERROR] while locating org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JDTCompiler
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
[ERROR] while locating org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.Compiler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jdt)
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 1 error
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0:compile (default-compile) on project com.codeaffine.util: Execution default-compile of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0:compile failed: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JdkLibraryInfoProvider was bound.
  while locating org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JDTCompiler
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.Compiler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jdt)

1 error
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default-compile of goal org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0:compile failed: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JdkLibraryInfoProvider was bound.
  while locating org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JDTCompiler
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.Compiler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jdt)

1 error
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) No implementation for org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JdkLibraryInfoProvider was bound.
  while locating org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.jdt.JDTCompiler
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  at ClassRealm[plugin>org.eclipse.tycho:tycho-compiler-plugin:1.4.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@b4aac2] (via modules: org.eclipse.sisu.wire.WireModule -> org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.PlexusBindingModule)
  while locating org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.Compiler annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=jdt)

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.inject.LazyBeanEntry.getValue(LazyBeanEntry.java:81)
    at org.eclipse.sisu.plexus.LazyPlexusBean.getValue(LazyPlexusBean.java:51)
    at java.util.AbstractMap.get(AbstractMap.java:187)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.compiler.manager.DefaultCompilerManager.getCompiler(DefaultCompilerManager.java:52)
    at copied.org.apache.maven.plugin.AbstractCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractCompilerMojo.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.tycho.compiler.AbstractOsgiCompilerMojo.execute(AbstractOsgiCompilerMojo.java:293)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    ... 21 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
```

Here is the parent pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <groupId>tr.com.dummy</groupId>
    <artifactId>parent</artifactId>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <tycho.version>1.4.0</tycho.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        ...
    </repositories>

    <modules>
        ...
    </modules>

    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
<!--                <plugin> -->
<!--                    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                    <configuration> -->
<!--                        <source>${java.version}</source> -->
<!--                        <target>${java.version}</target> -->
<!--                        <compilerId>jdt</compilerId> -->
<!--                        <compilerArgument>-err:nullAnnot,null</compilerArgument> -->
<!--                    </configuration> -->
<!--                    <dependencies> -->
<!--                        <dependency> -->
<!--                            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId> -->
<!--                            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-jdt</artifactId> -->
<!--                            <version>${tycho.version}</version> -->
<!--                        </dependency> -->
<!--                    </dependencies> -->
<!--                </plugin> -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                    <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
<!--            <plugin> -->
<!--                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId> -->
<!--                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId> -->
<!--                <configuration> -->
<!--                    <source>${java.version}</source> -->
<!--                    <target>${java.version}</target> -->
<!--                    <encoding>${project.build.sourceEncoding}</encoding> -->
<!--                    <compilerArgument>-proc:none</compilerArgument> -->
<!--                </configuration> -->
<!--            </plugin> -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <compilerArgs>
                        <args>-warn:-raw,unchecked</args>
                    </compilerArgs>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <resolver>p2</resolver>
<!--                    <pomDependencies>consider</pomDependencies> -->
<!--                    <target> -->
<!--                        <artifact> -->
<!--                            <groupId>tr.com.dummy</groupId> -->
<!--                            <artifactId>dummy.target</artifactId> -->
<!--                            <version>1.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version> -->
<!--                        </artifact> -->
<!--                    </target> -->
                    <environments>
                        <environment>
                            <os>win32</os>
                            <ws>win32</ws>
                            <arch>x86</arch>
                        </environment>
                    </environments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
                <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${tycho.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

I suspect the error is about compiler configuration so I tried different JDT/compiler configuration in the parent pom but nothing worked so far.

What am I missing here? What is the proper way to configure compiler to use JDT?

Thanks in advance.